# How to execute callback of async call on Java's main thread?

Tags: java, asynchronous, callback

Is there a way to force the execution of the callback to be executed on the main thread?

For example, in the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ListeningExecutorService executor = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10));
    Executor main_executor = MoreExecutors.directExecutor();

    Callable<String> asyncTask = () -> {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        return "Task executed by " + Thread.currentThread().getName().toString();
    };

    ListenableFuture<String> listenableFuture = executor.submit(asyncTask);

    Futures.addCallback(listenableFuture, new FutureCallback<String>() {
        public void onSuccess(String result) {
            System.out.println(
                    "Callback executed by " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " with return value " + result);
        }

        public void onFailure(Throwable thrown) {
            thrown.printStackTrace();
        }
    }, main_executor);

    Thread.sleep(2000);

    try {
        String result = listenableFuture.get();
        System.out.println("Future value was retrived by " + Thread.currentThread().getName().toString()
                + " with return value " + result);
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Thread.sleep(1000);
    executor.shutdown();
}
```

The output is:

```
Callback executed by pool-1-thread-1 with return value Task executed by pool-1-thread-1
Future value was retrived by main with return value Task executed by pool-1-thread-1
```

which mean the callback was execute by a worker thread, even though I specified the main thread while adding the callback, what am Imissing?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this.  The main thread is busy running `main`.

`directExecutor` doesn't mean "the main thread," it means "run on whichever thread finished the last piece of work."

Comment: Thank you, I guess I misunderstood documentation in that regard.

Comment: The doc says "Returns an Executor that runs each task in the thread that invokes execute," not "that runs each task in the thread that invokes directExecutor."

Comment: Though now that I look at it, while doing ```Futures.addCallback(...)```, the value of  main_executor is completely ignored?

Comment: No, it isn't ignored.  It's just that "whichever thread finished the last piece of work" is the thread from `executor`.